# How to efficiently block asio read until data becomes available on serial device?

Tags: serial-port, boost-asio, blocking, polling

I want to use asio to read from a serial device and process bytes when they become available.

When using `async_read_until` my callback gets called most of the time because of the end-of-file (EOF) error. I therefore need to exit the callback and register it again until data becomes available. This results in a busy loop, which I would like to prevent. Similar happens to `read_until` which immediately returns with the same EOF error.

For POSIX there is `poll` to efficiently wait until data becomes available on a device, but I would rather use portable (including Windows) asio functions to achieve a similar effect. On asio there is `asio::descriptor_base::bytes_readable` which would allow me to test beforehand if data is available, however I would have to test this in a active loop to block until data is available.

Is there a way in asio to only call a async callback when data is available? E.g. can I mask errors in `async_read_until` such that callbacks are not called on these errors?

Comment: Maybe you're looking for http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/reactor.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read data when it's available then I recommend using the [async_read_some](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_serial_port/async_read_some.html) function instead of `async_read_until`, see [Streams, Short Reads and Short Writes](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/streams.html).

A typical read handler would look like this:

```
void read_handler(const boost::system::error_code& error, size_t bytes_transferred)
{
  if (error != boost::asio::error::operation_aborted)
  {
    if (error)
      // handle error
    else
    {
      // process bytes_transferred data from the buffer
      // enable reception by calling async_read_some on the socket with a buffer
    }
  }
}
```